# Postgres/Psycopg: password authentication failed (with correct user/password)

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I'm receiving the following error when connecting to a remote Postgres 13 database server. The user and password *are* correct.

> psycopg.OperationalError: connection failed: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "someuser"

Things I tried:

- Using Psycopg2-binary
- Using Psycopg3[binary]
- The most permissive pg_hba.conf: host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust
- Also tried hostssl and md5 and password options
- Setting ssl = off
- Removing all "reject" lines from pg_hba.conf

Facts:

- User can connect via pgAdmin
- User can connect via psql
- Same Python code works against a different Postgres server
- postgres.conf specifies listen_addresses='*'
- postgres.conf is identical to the postgres.conf on the server that connects without problems.

```
import psycopg

HOST="<ip here>"
PORT=5432
DB="<dbname here>"
USER="<user here>"
PASS="<pass here>"
with psycopg.connect(host=HOST,port=PORT,dbname=DB,user=USER,password=PASS) as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        ....
```

I'm suspecting that perhaps the server that I cannot connect to has a stronger SSL setting, but I'm grasping at straws here. I also suspect both machines are created and controlled with the same puppet scripts, so should be very identical. Clearly the login is not blocked by firewalls, given the return error.

I've also tried adding `sslmode='required'` and passing a cert file, but that gives me an `certificate verify failed` errror. Both postgresql.conf have `ssl=on`.

**UPDATE:** I've been monitoring the logs, succesful connections show up, but never any authentication fails from Psycopg. Even at the highest debug5 level, nothing shows when the connection is attempted. In addition I've set `ssl = off` and removed all "reject" lines from pg_hba.conf.

Any ideas? Things I can check or try?

Comment: Look in the database server's log file for details on the failure.  Not all details are sent to the (unauthenticated, presumably hostile) client.

Comment: So this is weird. Nothing is logged when this happens (even at debug5). I know what this sounds like, feels like I'm not connecting to this particular server, but IP address and everything checks out...

Comment: Certainly sounds like you have more than one database running are connecting to the wrong one.  If the port and host are correct, then I don't know why.  Maybe some fancy networking environment is intercepting your connection and forwarding it elsewhere.

Comment: I'm having the same exact problem. Both when running POSTGRES installed locally and when uninstalling the local version and running using a Docker container.